# Electric field parallel to a hollow cylinder (outside)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields

Having trouble with a question my lecturer posted me.

> A thin-walled hollow circular glass tube, open at both ends, has a radius R and length L. The axis of the tube lies along the x axis, with the left end at the origin. The outer sides are rubbed with silk and acquire a net positive charge Q distributed uniformly. Determine the electric field at a location on the x axis, a distance w from the origin. (You may use Mathematica).
>
> Calculate the magnitude of the electric field at the location (x)
> when: R=6.3 cm, L=3.5 cm, w=8.3 cm, and Q=2.8 nC. Use units of N/C

[image]

How I've approached the problem:

So I've split my hollow cylinder into infinitesimally small rings. I'm defining r as the distance between the start of the cylinder to my small ring, and I get the following expression for the electric field of each small ring:

[image]

Substituting my values in I get:

[image]

I then try to integrate this with respect to r, on the interval from 0 to L (0.035) which gives me an answer of 76.3, which is wrong. I'm not sure why it would be wrong, would somebody be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Answer (score 1):

You have to change Q in the integral and substitute it for the differential charge on one of those infinitesimally small rings. I think that should change your result only by a factor of $\frac{1}{L}$

Comment: This looks like a good suggestion. You need the charge per unit area multiplied by the area of your infinitesimal ring - in practice that means charge per unit length which is charge divided by length as you say.